# How can I move the vertical position of a code block in CSS/HTML? Due to the different font being used, it appears lower than the rest of the text

Tags: html, css

I am using stylized code blocks in a program called Joplin. The program allows you to define your own styles via css. I am trying to move the code blocks up 1-2px so that they are aligned with the surrounding text:

[image]

Here's the CSS:

```css
.inline-code, .mce-content-body code, .jop-tinymce table code {
    border-width: 1px !important;
    border-color: #bdbdbd;
    background-color: #f3f3f3 !important;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em 0.2em 0.4em !important;
    border-radius: 0.27em !important;
    font-size: 13px !important;
    font-family: "Input Mono", "Roboto Mono", "Monospace" !important;
    margin-right: 0.2em !important;
    color: #292929 !important;
```

Does anyone know how I can "nudge" these code blocks up a couple pixels for visual continuity?

Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: If you want to move the code block up 2px for example, add to the style `position: relative; top: -2px;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented on your question, add `position: relative; top: -2px;` to move the code block up 2 pixels. For example:

```css
.inline-code, .mce-content-body code, .jop-tinymce table code {
    border-width: 1px !important;
    border-color: #bdbdbd;
    background-color: #f3f3f3 !important;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em 0.2em 0.4em !important;
    border-radius: 0.27em !important;
    font-size: 13px !important;
    font-family: "Input Mono", "Roboto Mono", "Monospace" !important;
    margin-right: 0.2em !important;
    color: #292929 !important;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
}
```

```html
This is <code class="inline-code">a code block</code>.
```